# Submitting a form dynamically created in AJAX success function in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have form that I created dynamically within the success function of an AJAX call.  I thought that, once this form is appended to the DOM, it would submit like a normal form in CodeIgniter.  However, when I click the submit button, it is sent to the appropriate controller, but none of the POST data is being picked up.

My initial form:

```
 <div id="editTicketOptions" class="alert alert-info" style="display:none">
     <form name="editTicketForm" id="editTicketForm" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="edit_ticket">Choose a Ticket:</label>
          <select name="edit_number" id="edit_number" class="form-control">
               <option value="">Choose one...</option>
               <?php foreach ($created_tickets as $ticket): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo($ticket->ticketId); ?>"><?php echo ($ticket->ticketId . " - " . $ticket->headline); ?></option>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My AJAX call:

```
$('#edit_number').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('ticket_system/edit_details'); ?>",
        dataType: "json",
       data:{
            'ticketId': $(this).val()
       },
       success: function(ticket){
            $("#headline_entry").remove();
            $("#description_entry").remove();
            $("#priority_entry").remove();
            $("#button_entry").remove();
            $("#editTicketForm").append("<div class='form-group' id='headline_entry'><label for='edit_headline'>Headline:</label><input type='text' class='form-control' name='edit_headline' id='edit_headline' required></div>");
            $("#editTicketForm").append("<div class='form-group' id='description_entry'><label for='edit_description'>Description:</label><textarea class='form-control' rows='3' name='edit_description' id='edit_description' required>" + ticket[0].description + "</textarea></div>");
            $("#editTicketForm").append("<div class='form-group' id='priority_entry'><label for='edit_priority'>Choose priority:</label><select name='edit_priority' id='edit_priority' class='form-control'><option selected value=" + ticket[0].priority + ">" + ticket[0].priority + "</option><option value='High'>High</option><option value='Medium'>Medium</option><option value='Low'>Low</option></select>");
            $("#editTicketForm").append("<div class='text-center' id='button_entry'><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' id='editTicketButton' value='Edit Ticket'></div>");
            $("#editTicketForm").attr("action", "<?php echo base_url('ticket_system/edit_ticket/'); ?>" + "/" +ticket[0].ticketId + " ");
        }
    });
});
```

My Controller Function:

```
public function edit_ticket()
{
    $ticketId = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $headline = $this->input->post('edit_headline');
    $description = $this->input->post('edit_description');
    $priority = $this->input->post('edit_priority');
    $edit_ticket = array(
        'ticketId' =>$ticketId,
        'headline' => $headline,
        'description' => $description,
        'priority' => $priority
    );

    $this->tickets->editTicket($edit_ticket);

    redirect('ticket_system/view_tickets');
}
```

I know it's not the prettiest code, but am I missing something simple here?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your controller method `edit_ticket()` is receiving POST information `$this->input->post(...)` but you are not setting your form to the method POST, thus sending GET information rather than POST.

**Solution:** add the attribute `method="POST"` to your form:

```
<form name="editTicketForm" id="editTicketForm" method="POST">
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple like that.  Drives me crazy!  Thanks so much for the help!